# XSLT transformations in Ruby and JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, nokogiri, rexml, xslt

Simple question: are there *any* solid XSLT libraries that work in both Ruby and JRuby?

- REXML works in both, but does not have XSLT support.
- [ruby-xslt](http://ruby-asp.rubyforge.org/ruby-xslt/files/README.html) doesn't work in JRuby.
- The latest [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) betas do support JRuby, but the support is still buggy and throws occasional NullPointerExceptions for XML input that works fine in Ruby.  (In particular, any transforms that don't result in valid XML cause it to barf, even if xsl:output is set to 'text'!)
- [JXslt](http://kfahlgren.com/blog/2007/03/02/borrowing-javas-xslt-support-for-ruby/) is just a wrapper for Java's Xalan/Saxon and doesn't work in Ruby.

Please tell me I'm missing something?

Comment: Given the resounding silence, apparently not.  For this and other reasons, we've given up on JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

A solid JRuby implementation of Nokogiri didn't appear until 1.5.0 was released in 2011. The latest versions have been pretty solid under JRuby.

Comment: JRuby/Nokogiri in general, or XSLT on the combination in particular?